# ¿Cómo crear un menú en Google Apps Script desde un objeto tipo JSON o matriz (array)?

Tags: json, array, google-apps-script, menú, google-apps-script-menu

¿Es posible crear un menú en las aplicaciones de Google a partir de un objeto del tipo JSON o matriz (*array*), sin tener que estar usando los métodos .addMenu(), .addItem(), .addSeparator() y .addSubMenu()?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema de usar los métodos citados?

Comment: En realidad ninguno, pero me gusta mas visualmente como se ve la creación de un menu estructurado en un objeto o array. ;)

Comment: No creo que ese vaya a ser un argumento de "venta" muy exitoso. ¿Has pensado publicar tu script en GitHub o alguna plataforma similar?

Comment: ¿Porque no?, si al fin de cuentas están los que le gusta jugosa, cocida y a punto medio. Y así para todos las cosas. Si, luego veré de publicarlo en GitHub. Gracias por todo nuevamente.

Comment: Pues suele ocurrir que yo creo una cosa y pasa otra por eso te preguntaba si lo publicarías es un espacio como GitHub donde existen otras formas de colaborar y podrían ser mejor para medir que tanto se usa un script como el tuyo, porque aquí para votar se requiere ser tener reputación, etc., etc.

Answer (score 4):

## MenuMaker v1.02 para Google Apps Script

Pseudo-clase para crear menús para las aplicaciones de Google a partir de un Objeto tipo JSON o Array.

*Funciona tanto en hojas de cálculo, documentos y formularios. Para ello se debe de Comentar/Descomentar las lineas que correspondan a cada servicio donde será utilizado el Script dentro de las primeras lineas de la función **MenuMaker***._

```
/* 
* MenuMaker v1.02 para Google Apps Script
* Crea menús a partir de objeto tipo JSON o array
* @author Elwyn
* @email wakeupneo33@gmail.com
*/

Array.prototype.last = function(value) {
    if( value != null ) this[this.length-1] = value;
    return this[this.length-1];
}

var MenuMaker_ = function( obj ){
  /* Comentar/Descomentar las siguientes lineas en base al servicio donde se esté ejecutando el Script */
  this.ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  //this.ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  //this.ui = FormApp.getUi();

  this.menu = [];
  if( obj instanceof Object ){
     this.addMenus( obj ).build();
  }
}

MenuMaker_.prototype.addMenu = function(caption) {
  this.menu.push( this.ui.createMenu(caption) );
  return this;
}

MenuMaker_.prototype.addMenus = function( obj ) {
  // Para menus multiples
  if( Array.isArray( obj ) &&  obj[0] instanceof Object ){
    for(var i=0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      this.addMenu( obj[i].caption || obj[i].name || obj[i][0] ).addItems( obj[i].items || obj[i][1] );
    }
  // o un solo menu
  } else {
      this.addMenu( obj.caption || obj.name || obj.submenu || obj[0] ).addItems( obj.items || obj[1] );
  }
  return this;
}

MenuMaker_.prototype.addItem = function(name, functionName) {
  this.menu.last().addItem(name, functionName);
  return this;
}

MenuMaker_.prototype.addItems = function(items) {
  if( !Array.isArray( items ) ) return this;
  for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    // El separador puede ser: null, string/array/object vacio o un string que comience con "sep" (no sencible a mayusculas )
    if( items[i] == null || items[i].length == 0 || /^sep/i.test( items[i] ) || Object.keys(items[i]).length === 0 || typeof items[i]['separator'] !== 'undefined' ) {
      this.addSeparator();
    // Items definido en un objeto
    } else if( typeof items[i]['name'] !== 'undefined' && typeof items[i]['items'] === 'undefined' ){
      this.menu.last().addItem(items[i].name, items[i].functionName || items[i].fnName || items[i].func || 'undefined');
    // SubMenu definido en un objeto o en un array. En el caso de array, el  primer elemento es el nombre y el segundo un array con items.
    } else if( typeof items[i]['items'] !== 'undefined' || (Array.isArray(items[i]) && typeof items[i][0] === 'string' && items[i][1] instanceof Array) ){
      this.addSubMenu( MenuMaker().addMenus( items[i] ) );
    // Items definido en un array. El primer elemento es el nombre y el segunto el nombre de la funcion
    } else {
      this.menu.last().addItem(items[i][0], items[i][1]);
    }
  }
  return this;
}

MenuMaker_.prototype.addSeparator = function() {
  this.menu.last().addSeparator();
  return this;
}

MenuMaker_.prototype.addSubMenu = function(submenu) {
  if( typeof submenu['getLastMenu'] === 'function' ){
    submenu = submenu.getLastMenu();
  }
  this.menu.last().addSubMenu( submenu );
  return this;
}

MenuMaker_.prototype.getLastMenu = function() {
  return this.menu.last();
}

MenuMaker_.prototype.build = function() {
  for( var i=0; i < this.menu.length; i++ ){
    this.menu[i].addToUi();
  }
}


function MenuMaker( obj ) {
  return new MenuMaker_( obj );
}
```

### Ejemplo de uso

```
var miMenu = {
  caption:"Menu 1",
  items:[
     {name:"Opción 1", functionName:"fnOpcion1"},
     {name:"Opción 2", functionName:"fnOpcion2"},
     {separator:true},
     {
       submenu:"Opción 3",
       items:[
         {name:"Opc3 Sub1", functionName:"fnOpc3Sub1"}
       ]
     }
  ]
};

function onOpen() {
  MenuMaker( miMenu );
}
```

Otra forma de poder realizar lo mismo es creando una matriz multi-dimensional donde el primer elemento siempre será considerado el nombre del menú o sub-menú u opción de menú en cuestión y el segundo elemento podrá ser el nombre de la función para la opción, o un nuevo array para definir los sub-menus.
Los separadores serán considerados al ingresar una matriz u objeto o cadena de caracteres que comience con "sep" (no sensible a mayúsculas) o vacía, en alguno de los elementos de los arrays de items.

```
var miMenu = [
  'Menu 1', 
  [
     ["Opción A", "fnOptionA"],
     ["Opción B", "fnOptionB"],
     null,
     ["Opción C",
        [
           ['Opc-C Sub-1','fnOpcCsub1']
        ]
     ]
  ]
];

function onOpen() {
   MenuMaker( miMenu );
}
```

O si se quieren, también se puede combinar todo como uno quiera.
Para los nombres de menus se puede usar la propiedad ***caption:*** o ***name**:*
Para los nombres de sub-menus, ***submenu:*** o ***name:***
Para los nombres de las funciones, ***functionName:*** o ***func:*** o ***fnName:***
Para los separadores se puede usar ****separator:**** seguido de cualquier valor o un elemento nulo o vacío
Para los Items de los menus o submenus se usa la propiedad ****items:**** y su elementos será siempre contenidos dentro de una matriz (array), ya sean representados como objetos o arrays.

```
var miMenu = [
  { name: 'Menú 1', 
    items: [
        {name:"Opción 01", func:"fnOpcion01"},
        ["Opción 02", "fnOpcion02"],
        "SePaRaDoR",
        [
          "Opción 03",
           [
              {name:'Opc-03 Sub-01', fnName:'fnOpc03Sub01'}
           ]
        ]
     ]
  },
  ["Menú 2",[["Opc 1", [["Opc1 Sub1", [[ "Opc Sub1-A",[["Opc1 Sub1-A 01", "fnM2opc1sub1A01"],[],["Opc1 Sub1-A 02", "fnM2opc1sub1A02"]]]]]]]]]
];

function onOpen() {
   MenuMaker( miMenu );
}
```

Los ejemplos muestran todas las alternativas posibles de estructuración, luego cada uno elige la que mas le agrade.

También es posible la creación de esta forma:

```
 MenuMaker()
  .addMenu("Menú 0")
  .addItems([{name:"Opción A1", func:"fnOpt1"},{name:"Opción A2", func:"fnOpt2"}])
  .build();
```

Comment: Interesante aporte. Tal vez quieras agregar la explicación de que el código es para las hojas de cálculo de Google y lo que debería cambiarse para que funcione en las demás aplicaciones.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso Rubén, ahí modifique el código para que funcione tanto en las hojas de calculo, como en los documentos y los formularios.

Comment: No me convence la solución que implementaste porque las llamadas a los servicios de Apps Script consumen relativamente mucho tiempo. Me parece que sería mejor poner instrucciones de comentar las llamadas que no se requieren y dejar habilitada la que se ocupe.

Comment: Ok. ahora lo corrijo ¿Sabes si existe una forma de saber donde uno está ejecutando los Scripts?

Comment: Esa sí que es una buena pregunta. ¿Te animas a publicarla?

Comment: Supongo que tendría sentido en el caso de tener la intención de crear una librería "universal", porque en el caso de agregar manualmente el código, el costo en tiempo de ejecución podría ser una desventaja importante.

Comment: Jajajaj.. dale.. veo como redactarlo y la hago. ;) Gracias por todo.