# Tengo un problema con una variable y no me doy cuenta de cuál es el error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Debo generar un Spreadsheet con las mesas (titular, asistente o veedor) a las que debe asistir cada profesor.

```
function crearXlsxProfe(profe) {
  var name = 'Mesas del Prof. '+ profe ;
  var planillaNueva = SpreadsheetApp.create(name, 50,15);
  var data = filtrarProfe(profe);
  SpreadsheetApp.open(planillaNueva);
  
  /*Busca archivo recien creado
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(name);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
  */
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet.getRange("A1:I").setValue(data);
   
}
```

La variable `var profe = 'Juan Pérez'` está declarada de manera global.

Como se darán cuenta, la función está incompleta. No logro crear el archivo *'Mesas del Prof. Juan Pérez'*. En lugar de eso `var name = 'Mesas del Prof. '+ profe ;` genera un archivo *'Mesas del Prof. undefined'*. Evidentemente, la función no recoge la variante global... o no sé en qué me estaré equivocando.
Finalmente, no sé (y no encuentro) la forma de abrir la planilla recién creada y volcar los datos generados por `function filtrarProfe()`. Esta claro que `SpreadsheetApp.open(planillaNueva)` no es la manera correcta de hacerlo. Entiendo que *open* requiere del parámetro *file* y no *name* para funcionar. Y no puedo utilizar openById() u openByUrl(), ya que al ser una planilla creada dentro de la función, no hay forma de conocer esos parámetros...

En resumen:

<s>a) ¿Por qué la función no reconoce la variable global *profe*?, y</s> <sup>Véase la segunda actualización de progreso</sup>
b) ¿Cómo hago para abrir el archivo recién creado, para poder editarlo?

---

Actualizaciones de progreso

Primera

Encontre un video en YouTube con esta línea, que debería permitirme abrir el archivo recién creado, pero aún no logro que funcione. En principio porque aún no logro que reconozca la variable `profe`.

```
var profe = 'Juan Pérez'

function crearXlsxProfe(profe) {
  var name = 'Mesas del Prof. '+ profe ;
  SpreadsheetApp.create(name, 50,15);
  var data = filtrarProfe(profe);
  SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFilesByName(name).next());
}
```

Segunda

Ahora logro crear el archivo con el nombre del profesor, pero aún no logro abrirlo...

```
var profe = "Guerrero, Ignacio";

function crearXlsxProfe(name) {
  var sSName = 'Mesas del Prof. '+ name ;
  SpreadsheetApp.create(sSName, 50,15);
  var data = filtrarProfe(profe);
  SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFilesByName(sSName).next());
   
} 

crearXlsxProfe(profe);
```

Final

Así queda el código. Funciona, aunque hay un par de 'hipos' que me molestan.

```
var profe = "Guerrero, Ignacio";


function filtrarProfe(name) {
  
  /* Una mala solución a mi problema. 
  La función sólo levanta la variable global 'profe' si ejecuto todo el código,
  así que aquí la agrego 'manualmente' para no recibir errores de ejecución. */ 
  var name = "Guerrero, Ignacio";
  
  /* Array con los nombres de las solapas*/
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id-de-la-hoja-de-cálculos');
  var sheets = sSheet.getSheets();
  var mesas = [];

  //Por cada solapa del archivo...
  for (i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    var lenguaje = [sheets[i].getName()];
    var data = sSheet.getSheetByName(lenguaje).getDataRange().getValues();
    var filas = data.filter(function(fila){
      for (var c=3;c<6;c++) {
        var esProfe = fila[c];
        if (esProfe === name) {
          return fila.join(";");
        } 
      } 
    });

    for (f=0;f<filas.length;f++){
      var filasnew = lenguaje.concat(filas[f]);
      mesas.push(filasnew);
    }

  }
  /* A ver si todo está bien... */
  Logger.log(mesas);
  return mesas;
}


function crearSSProfe(name) {
  var sSName = 'Mesas del Prof. '+ name;
  SpreadsheetApp.create(sSName, 50,9);
  
}


function editarSSProfe(name) {
  var name = 'Guerrero, Ignacio';
  var sSName = 'Mesas del Prof. '+ name;
  var gFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(sSName);
  var file = gFile.next();
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
  var mesas = filtrarProfe(name); 
  sSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, mesas.length, mesas[0].length).setValues(mesas);

} 

//Logger.log(filtrarProfe(profe))
//crearXlsxProfe(profe);
//openSSProfe(profe);
```

<s>Esta línea `sSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, mesas.length, mesas[0].length).setValues(mesas);` me tira el siguiente error:
`Exception: El número de columnas de los datos no coincide con el del intervalo. Los datos tienen 12 y el intervalo, 9. at editarSSProfe(Código:63:73)`, pero aún así vuelca el array `mesas` en la hoja de cálculos correctamente.</s> Solucionado. Era un error en una pestaña.

<s>Lo último que tengo que aprender a hacer es a correr el código correctamente. Hasta ahora estoy haciendo trampa al poner la variable `name` de forma local en cada función.</s>
La idea ahora es levantar el nombre de cada profesor (92) desde la hoja CRONOGRAMA, generar una hoja PROFESORES y correr el presente script para cada profesor.
Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: No veo desde qué contexto llamas a `crearXlsxProfe()`, es ahí donde debes revisar qué pasa con la variable `profe`

Comment: Hola. De momento no estoy llamando la función desde ningún lugar. Solo la estoy corriendo con el depurador. Probablemente esté utilizando mal la consola...

Comment: ¿Cómo debería declara la variable?

Comment: El área de respuestas es para responder a la pregunta. Para agregar elementos nuevos debes pulsar en [edit] y agregarlos en la misma pregunta. Si observas, `crearXlsxProfe()` debe recibir un parámetro que es el nombre del profesor, y ser llamado desde alguna parte. Eso es lo primero que necesitas tener claro, de lo contrario estarás perdido en tu propio código, como de hecho está ocurriendo ahora. Tómate un poco de tiempo para analizar, entender, explicar el contexto. Dado ese paso será más simple resolver los otros problemas.

Comment: Gracias por la indicación. Ya está enmendado.

Comment: Volviendo al tema, @ACedano. Creo que hay algo que no entiendo o que no sé (mucho, de hecho).
Como muestro en el UPDATE: Tengo declarado el nombre Juan Pérez en la variable `profe`. ¿No es correcto hacerlo así?

Comment: Es correcto eso, pero **debe haber un contexto, un lugar, desde el cual llames a `crearXlsxProfe()`**. ¿Cuál es ese contexto, desde qué parte de tu código hay que llamar a `crearXlsxProfe()`?

Comment: @ACedano. UPDATE 2 . ¿A esto se refería?

Comment: A eso me refiero. Ahí debería llamarse a `crearXlsxProfe()`, recibiendo el parámetro `profe` que es `Guerrero, Ignacio`. ¿Así no funciona? ¿Qué problema presenta el código?

Comment: Sí y no. Con esto está resuelto la mitad del problema.
Yo estoy sacando datos del spreadsheet `cronograma`. Una vez filtrados los datos y almacenados en un string debo crear un nuevo spreadsheet para ese profesor. Hasta aquí está logrado. El problema ahora es, una vez creado el nuevo spreadsheet debo poder abrirlo y convertirlo en mi spreadsheet activo para poder guardar los datos del string en él.
Hasta ahora no he logrado abrirlo.

Comment: Tendrías quizá que guardar una referencia al objeto que se crea aquí: `SpreadsheetApp.create(sSName, 50,15);` para luego usarlo para abrirlo, sea por su nombre, sea por su id, sea por su URL. No sé, no tengo experiencia con esto, pero debería hacerse sin mayor dificultad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus consejos, @ACedano.

Comment: La primera parte de la pregunta parece salir sobrando. Deberías sólo incluiir un [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén Recién leo tu comentario. Me doy cuenta de que estoy rompiendo muchos protocolos. Acabo de editar mi pregunta con la versión (casi) final del script. Seguramente no es un ejemplo mínimo. Sí completo. No verificable, ya que haría falta el spreadsheet del CRONOGRAMA para hacer funcionar correctamente las funciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De la segunda actualización de progreso

> Ahora logro crear el archivo con el nombre del profesor, pero aún no
> logro abrirlo...

Para abrir un archivo usando Google Apps Script debes usar código del lado del cliente ya que esto no se puede hacer directamente usando sólo código del lado del servidor.

Por usar código del lado del cliente me refiero a usar el servicio HTML para crear un diálogo o panel lateral que al cargarse llame una función JavaScript que abra tu hoja de cálculo. Puedes ver un ejemplo del código en mi respuesta a [Cómo abrir un Doc de Google Drive en la UI de Google sheet?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/296965/65)

---

Con respecto a los métodos de la clase SpreadsheetApp que "abren" una hoja de cálculo:

- open(file)
- openById(id)
- openByUrl(url)

Los métodos anteriores no abren la hoja de cálculo en el navegador / computadora del usuario, lo que hacen es "abrirla" del lado del servidor. En lo personal a quienes están empezando con las hojas de cálculo de Google y Apps Script no les recomiendo utilizar los métodos que hacen referencia a algo activo / actual como :

- getActiveSheet()
- getActiveRange()
- getActiveCell()
- activate()
- getCurrentCell()

En su lugar usen los métodos que usan un valor u objeto para obtener el elemento deseado. Les ahorrá muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, Rubén. Mi error estaba en suponer que  `SpreadsheetApp.open()` abría la hoja en una pestaña del navegador. No lo hace. Lo que abre es el servicio. La hoja pasa a ser activa y editable.

Comment: @IgnacioGuerrero He editado mi respuesta porque no me queda claro que estas entendiendo por "la hoja pasa aser activa".

Comment: Precisamente. Ese era mi error. Pensaba que el método `open()` abría la hoja de cálculos en mi navegador (cliente), no en el servidor. Estuve horas probando distintos métodos, y nada... Hace mucho timepo que no escribo código, y Google Apps Script es nuevo para mí. Recién le estoy 'cazando la onda'.
Gracias por tus consejos.